# MediaPlayer Android Studio makes my app work slow

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have the next doubt, I was working in an application that play sound in streaming from firebase. For the first time the app work correctly, but when I include admob dependencies and advertise in application, when I play the sound, the app works very slowly in emulator and in real device, why?

Here is my code, the problem with slow starts when playAudio.setOnClickListener...

```
public class CuentoMediaPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    private ImageView appBarImage;
    private Button playAudio, stopAudio, pauseAudio;
    private Cuento cuento;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    private StorageReference httpsReference;

    private boolean pause = false;
    private SeekBar seekBar;

    private Runnable mUpdateSeekbar;
    private Handler mSeekbarUpdateHandler;

    private TextView currentTime, finishTime;
    private ProgressBar progressBarMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cuento_media_player);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        cuento = (Cuento) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Cuento");
        httpsReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(cuento.getUrl());
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(cuento.getTitle());

        progressBarMediaPlayer = findViewById(R.id.progressBarMediaPlayer);
        progressBarMediaPlayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        currentTime = findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
        finishTime = findViewById(R.id.finishTIme);

        mSeekbarUpdateHandler = new Handler();
        mUpdateSeekbar = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seekBar.setProgress(mMediaplayer.getCurrentPosition());
                int seconds = (seekBar.getProgress() / 1000) % 60 ;
                int minutes = ((seekBar.getProgress() / (1000*60)) % 60);
                currentTime.setText(String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
                mSeekbarUpdateHandler.postDelayed(this, 50);
            }
        };



        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
                Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        appBarImage = findViewById(R.id.app_bar_image);
        playAudio = findViewById(R.id.playAudio);
        stopAudio = findViewById(R.id.stopAudio);
        pauseAudio = findViewById(R.id.pauseAudio);


        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    mMediaplayer.seekTo(progress);
                    int seconds = (progress / 1000) % 60 ;
                    int minutes = ((progress / (1000*60)) % 60);
                    currentTime.setText(String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(cuento.getImage()).into(appBarImage);

        playAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (pause == true) {
                    pause = false;
                    playAudio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mMediaplayer.start();
                    mSeekbarUpdateHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateSeekbar, 0);
                } else {
                    progressBarMediaPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    httpsReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            try {
                                mMediaplayer.setDataSource(uri.toString());
                                mMediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(CuentoMediaPlayerActivity.this);
                                mMediaplayer.prepareAsync();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });


        pauseAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mMediaplayer != null && mMediaplayer.isPlaying()){
                    pause = true;
                    pauseAudio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    playAudio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mMediaplayer.pause();
                    mSeekbarUpdateHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateSeekbar);
                }
            }
        });

        stopAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mMediaplayer != null) {
                    pause = true;
                    stopAudio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    playAudio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mMediaplayer.pause();
                    mMediaplayer.seekTo(0);
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        seekBar.setMax(mMediaplayer.getDuration());
        int seconds = (seekBar.getMax() / 1000) % 60 ;
        int minutes = ((seekBar.getMax() / (1000*60)) % 60);
        finishTime.setText(String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
        progressBarMediaPlayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        playAudio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mSeekbarUpdateHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateSeekbar, 0);
        mMediaplayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        if(mMediaplayer != null){
            mMediaplayer.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

and my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: did you  check with fast internet connection?

Comment: Run your media player in Service and whenever want to play. Just call the service,

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Comment: Yes, I check my Internet connection and it's fast.

Comment: The service sounds good, but I never work with something like this, any example?

Comment: Sorry I didn't actually read the question but my default comment when it comes to MediaPlayer is: drop it, use ExoPlayer instead.